# Calling super and mutating state in react

Tags: reactjs

[React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) say we shouldn't mutate `this.state` without using `this.setState`.
However it's efficient to have an init state var handy for resetting  forms and other similar situations.
[1](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) As far as I understand my implementation below comply with react docs regarding state mutation am I correct?

```
export default class SomeComp extends Component {
  initState = {
    demo: true,
    company: '',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    options: ''
  }

  state = {...this.initState }
...
```

[2] I understand that we should only really use super if we have to call this in a constructor in our class. something like the following:

```
export default class SomeComp extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super(props, state)
  this.props... //do something
  this.state... //do some more
 }
...
```

Am I correct and can you please give a common real world use case for using this in the constructor?

Comment: If state is simple, do as in #1, if complex, do as in #2. But make sure your syntax is correct, and `this props...` is never altered within the constructor, but it can be consumed there.

Comment: What do you mean by simple and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below points from [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor):

- The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted
- When implementing the constructor for a `React.Component` subclass, you should call `super(props)` before any other statement. Otherwise, `this.props` will be `undefined` in the `constructor`, which can lead to bugs.
- Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in the constructor. For those use cases, use `componentDidMount()` instead
- The constructor: the right place to initialize state. To do so, just assign an object to `this.state`; don’t try to call `setState()` from the constructor. The constructor is also often used to bind event handlers to the class instance.
- If you **don’t** initialize state and you don’t bind methods, **you don’t** need to implement a constructor for your React component.

Things to noice:

- You have `this.props... //do something` which will not work as you can't change props.
- `super` should be called as `super(props)`. you can't pass state and you don't need to.

```js
class SomeComp1 extends React.Component {
  state =  {
    demo: true,
    company: 'example',
    name: '',
    email: '',
    options: ''
  };
  
 render() {
  return <div>company1: {this.state.company} </div>;
 }
}


class SomeComp2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
      demo: true,
      company: 'example',
     name: '',
      email: '',
      options: ''
    };
  }
  
 render() {
  return <div>company2: {this.state.company} </div>;
 }
}
 
 
 ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <SomeComp1 />
    <SomeComp2 />
   </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: In my first example I'm init the state but not calling a constructor is that legal?

Comment: @S.Schenk yes you can but is not recommend. you can always try it your self. I updated my code to show both examples working.